# Finding the point on a line closest to another point not on the line

Tags: calculus, vectors

I am trying to solve the following question:
Let $L$ be the line passing through the point $A(5,-6, 7)$ parallel to the x–axis. Write down the coordinates of the point B on L which is closest to $C(1, 3, 4)$.

This is what I have tried doing so far:
Since the line is parallel to the x-axis, the equation of the line is:
$L = (5, -6, 7) + t(1, 0, 0)$
So the coordinates of the point B will be:
$x = 5+t$
$y=-6$
$z=7$

I have got the $y$ and $z$ coordinates, but I am unable to find the $x$-coordinate because of the scalar, $t$.

Could someone please check whether I am on the right track, and help me find the $x$-coordinate? Thanks :)

Comment: Good job so far, you've got a parametric equation for your line. Now, you want to minimise the distance to $C$. What is the formula for distance between two points? Hint: pythagoras...

Comment: I used the dot product method, as given in one of the answers. Thanks :)

Comment: Good work. I was actually going to suggest using the formula in Peter Woolfit's answer and then ignore of the $y$ and $z$ components which are constant, reducing the minimisation problem to solving for when the $x$ component is $0$. The dot product is also perfectly valid, but I'm a fan using the most elementary methods possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very straightforwatd method using dot product. For the line equation $$\underline{r}=\underline{a}+\lambda\underline{b},$$where $\underline {a}$ is a known fixed point on the line and $\underline{b}$ is the direction of the line, then the closest point to $P$ with position vector $\underline{p}$ is found by solving the equation $$(\underline{r}-\underline{p})\cdot\underline{b}=0$$ to obtain the parameter value for the foot of the perpendicular from $P$ to the line.

In this case, you have $$\underline{r}-\underline{p}=\left(\begin{matrix}5\\-6\\7\end{matrix}\right)+\lambda\left(\begin{matrix}1\\0\\0\end{matrix}\right)-\left(\begin{matrix}1\\3\\4\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}4+\lambda\\-9\\3\end{matrix}\right)$$

Therefore $$\left(\begin{matrix}4+\lambda\\-9\\3\end{matrix}\right)\cdot\left(\begin{matrix}1\\0\\0\end{matrix}\right)=0\Rightarrow \lambda=-4$$

Hence $$\underline{r}=\left(\begin{matrix}1\\-6\\7\end{matrix}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was looking for a method like this one. However, I do not quite understand the logic of $(r - p) . b = 0$ Could you please help me understand this? Thanks

Comment: The line joining P to the foot of the perpendicular must be perpendicular to the direction of the line. This is only possible for a unique value of $\lambda$

Answer (score 3):

You are correct so far. There's actually an easy way to intuit the answer. We travel parallel to the $x$ axis, so the best we can do is to get the $x$-coordinate of the point on $L$ as close to the $x$ coordinate of $C$ as possible. This is obviously achieved when $x=1$, giving $B=(1,-6,7)$.

However, I will give a more formal answer as well which you can use in a general setting.

All you have to do is write a formula for the distance between $C$ and an arbitrary point on $L$, and then minimize that distance. We use the Euclidean distance formula:

$$d=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2+(z_1-z_2)^2}$$

In our case, we have $B=(x_1,y_1,z_1)=(5+t,-6,7)$ and $C=(x_2,y_2,z_2)=(1,3,4)$. Hence our distance formula is
$$d=\sqrt{(5+t-1)^2+(-6-3)^2+(7-4)^2}=\sqrt{(4+t)^2+90}$$

Now we note that this function is minimized in the same place as
$$(4+t)^2+90$$
Taking a derivative and setting equal to $0$, we get

$$2(4+t)=0\hspace{10mm}\implies\hspace{10mm}t=-4$$

Hence the distance is minimized when $t=-4$, which is when $B=(1,-6,7)$ as we originally concluded.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This made a lot of sense, but I actually prefer the method by the other user. I wish I was able to accept two answers...

Comment: @John I'm glad to help :). No need to worry about the accepting - the system is designed so that you have to choose which answer you most liked, and if you prefer the other method then that's the answer you should accept.

Answer (score 1):

Try to merge algebra with geometry within you own mind. The answer should be obvious with few calculations.

[image]

Comment: Haha a nice and very inventive answer :)